# Canvas LMS REST API Quiz creation

Tags: canvas-lms

I'm having an issue with quiz creation using the Canvas REST API:

I can create a new quiz with `title` set.

I can add N questions with the following parameters set:

- `question_name`
- `question_text`
- `question_type`
- `points_possible`
- `answers`

When I look at my quizzes page, I can see the quiz exists, but it only shows that 1 question has been created for the quiz. I have to go to the quiz page, click the **Edit** button and then save the quiz for all of the questions to show up on the quizzes page.

What am I missing in this workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, for anyone interested in this question, the best solution I've been able to find is a hack. I tried doing comparisons of the quiz model data structure returned both before and after manually saving the quiz. There were some trivial differences, but only a couple meaningful ones. The only relevant difference was in the `question_count` attribute. It isn't being updated after adding questions.

**To "fix" this**: after adding your questions, manually update the `question_count` attribute (via a `PUSH`).

Perhaps this is a bug, perhaps I don't know what I'm doing. Either way, if anyone else has a better understanding of the Canvas REST API, please comment or provide a better answer.

Comment: The documentation (https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/quiz_questions.html) suggests that this part of the API is still in beta, which to me makes it plausible that this is simply a bug.

Comment: If anyone is seeing this as the accepted answer, *and* if there is now a proper fix to this bug, please post an answer with that information. I will happily select your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this same issue and here's a possible fix:  Create the quiz first with `published` set to `False`. Add your questions.  Then `edit` the quiz (https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/quizzes.html#method.quizzes/quizzes_api.update) to set `published` to `True`.  Then add any overrides, etc.